# DNS resolution to the local lan

Tags: networking

I am new to eOS and really dig it.  I noticed that my workstation (out of the box eOS) cannot resolve hosts on my lan.

I have a small DNS Domain (lan.local) which I use to manage local machines like

icemaker.lan.local

I noticed that while my host can resolve Internet Domains, when I try to ping icemaker.lan.local the can't be resolved.  Previous to this install, I was using Fedora workstation and DNS worked as expected

---

SystemD failed at DNS configration :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elementary OS uses a service, systemd-resolved.service, to manage DNS lookups. This service is used by many Linux distributions, such as Ubuntu, the distribution on which elementary is built. Take a look at this similar question in the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange and see if this doesn't answer your question.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442598/how-to-configure-systemd-resolved-and-systemd-networkd-to-use-local-dns-server-f

Comment: Hmm, so it sounds like this is an unfixable bug.  The workaround seems hamfisted. Thanks  for the tip.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration in this.  It really helped.

Comment: SO we are saying that by default Elementary OS can't do local DNS lookups?